# SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER in Firefox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

When I run this, I get SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER in firefox. What should I do with it? I'm a code newbie so your advice is much appreciated. 
I use
OS
Mac High Sierra 10.13.3
Selenium Version 3.11.0
Browser Firefox 59.0.1﻿

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

import csv
import os
import random
import time

class BingEnter(object):

    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.explicit_wait = 3
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.login_url = "https://login.live.com/"

    def login(self):
        self.driver.get(self.login_url)
        email_input = self.driver.find_element_by_name("loginfmt")
        email_input.send_keys(self.email)

        self.driver.find_element_by_id("idSIButton9").click()

        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.explicit_wait)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, 
        "idSIButton9")))
        password_input = self.driver.find_element_by_name("passwd")
        password_input.send_keys(self.password)

        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.explicit_wait)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, 
        "idTd_PWD_KMSI_Cb")))

        self.driver.find_element_by_id("idSIButton9").click()



with open('bing_account.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        user_id = row[0]
        password = row[1]

    bing_enter = BingEnter(user_id, password)
    bing_enter.login()
```

Comment: Do you normally access the internet via a proxy?

Comment: I use vpn occasionally. Does that matter with this case?

Comment: You can see this particular error when your company uses a proxy that does SSL inspection. In that case, it can be necessary to configure Firefox with a special root certificate. Not sure about the VPN though.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your advice. I actually changed from Firefox() to Chrome() and it worked.  I have another question. Could you suggest how to run this code via VPN ( ip address in America)? Is there any good reference?

Comment: Traffic is normally routed through a VPN connection automatically by the OS, so you don't usually have to do anything special as far as applications are concerned. That said, it may still be worth checking with your VPN provider in case they require any special configuration. I'm afraid I don't know of any general reference.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your advice again!